# Detect multiple includes of same javascript files/libraries

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on an html page in which a buttload of jQuery libraries are being loaded dynamically so there arises a chance of the same library being loaded twice. How can I detect whether the same file is being loaded twice or not in order to avoid complications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do reliably. I have only seen one attempt at it, but it didn't work reliably in any browser. Look at [this](http://numist.net/post/2010/include-guard-for-javascript.html).

It might be possible by letting each js file define some function unique to that file, and only including itself if that function does not exist. Similair to C/C++ include guard.
But dunno how to get it to work properly, and it would not include existing js files, such as jQuery.